# iOS: objective-C, facebook and twitter implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do you combine these 2 functions?
If i run it like this, I get this on Xcode `error: duplicate declaration of method 'application:openURL:options:'`. The idea is to implement facebook and twitter login buttons.

```
// Twitter
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
  return [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:app openURL:Url options:options];
}

// Facebook
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                             annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

Comment: BOOL handled = NO; if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] ...]) { handled = YES; } else if {[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] ...]} { handled = YES; } return handled; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handledByFacebook = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                          openURL:url
                                                                sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                                       annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];

  BOOL handledByTwitter = [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                                        options:options]; 

  return handledByFacebook || handledByTwitter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you dude. You are awesome.